# Webgl fragment shader transparency on pixel that has already been colored

Tags: webgl, alpha, fragment-shader

I just learned about Webgl a few days ago, and I am still a bit confused about transparency behavior.  I am trying to draw some circles inside a triangle using a fragment shader.  Everything appears to be working alright until I have two triangles overlapping.  My fragment shader determines if the point is in the circle or not, and then sets the color to either (1.,0.,0.,1.) if it is inside, or (1.,0.,0.,0.) if it is not.

The behavior I am expecting is that when the fragment shader sets a pixel to (1.,0.,0.,0.) that has already been colored (1.,0.,0.,1.), it will appear as (1.,0.,0.,1.).  However, it appears colored the same color as the background.
I have tried to turn on blend mode with the following, but it still doesn't seem to be working:

```
gl.enable( gl.BLEND );
gl.blendEquation( gl.FUNC_ADD );
gl.blendFunc( gl.ONE_MINUS_CONSTANT_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
```

I have attached my code below.

```js
const vertexShader = `

attribute vec4 aPosition;
attribute vec4 aCenter;
varying vec4 pos;
varying vec4 center;

void main() {
    center=aCenter;
    pos=aPosition;
    gl_Position = aPosition;
}
`;


const fragmentShader = `
precision mediump float;

varying vec4 pos;
varying vec4 center;

void main() {
    float inside = pow(pos.x - center.x, 2.0) + pow(pos.y - center.y, 2.0);
    float val=max(sign(pow(center.z, 2.0)-inside),0.);
    vec4 color=vec4(1.,0.,0.,val);
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
`;


const DEG_TO_RAD = 0.0174532925;
const TRI_HEIGHT_MOD = 2;
// build simple circle
var points = [];
var centers = [];
function buildCircle(center, r) {
    let angles=[0,120,240];
    for(let k=0;k<angles.length;k++){
      centers.push(center[0]);
      centers.push(center[1]);
      centers.push(r);
      var x=r * TRI_HEIGHT_MOD * Math.cos(angles[k] * DEG_TO_RAD) + center[0];
      var y=r * TRI_HEIGHT_MOD * Math.sin(angles[k] * DEG_TO_RAD) + center[1];
      points.push(x);
      points.push(y);
    } 
}

buildCircle([-.3,0],.5);
buildCircle([0,0],.5);



function loadShadersFromString(gl,vertexSource,fragmentSource){
  // first compile the vertex shader
  var vertexShader = gl.createShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(vertexShader,vertexSource);
  gl.compileShader(vertexShader);
  
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(vertexShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
          console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(vertexShader));
          return null;
      }
  
  // now compile the fragment shader
  var fragmentShader = gl.createShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER);
  gl.shaderSource(fragmentShader,fragmentSource);
  gl.compileShader(fragmentShader);
  
  if (!gl.getShaderParameter(fragmentShader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS)) {
          console.log(gl.getShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader));
          return null;
      }

  // OK, we have a pair of shaders, we need to put them together
  // into a "shader program" object
  var shaderProgram = gl.createProgram();
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
  gl.attachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
  gl.linkProgram(shaderProgram);

  if (!gl.getProgramParameter(shaderProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS)) {
    alert("Could not initialise shaders");
  }
  return shaderProgram;
}

function loadScene() {
  // Get A WebGL context
  /** @type {HTMLCanvasElement} */
  var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
  var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl");
  if(!gl){return;}
  webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  // gl.drawElements(gl.LINES, given_animal.vertex_indices_buffer.numItems, gl.UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
  // gl.lineWidth(width);

  // setup GLSL program
  // var program = webglUtils.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["vertex-shader-3d", "fragment-shader-3d"]);
  var program = loadShadersFromString(gl,vertexShader,fragmentShader);

  // look up where the vertex data needs to go.
  var positionLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aPosition");
  var centerLocation = gl.getAttribLocation(program, "aCenter");

  // Create a buffer to put positions in
  var positionBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(points),gl.STATIC_DRAW);
  var centerBuffer = gl.createBuffer();
  gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, centerBuffer);
  gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER,new Float32Array(centers),gl.STATIC_DRAW);

  drawScene();
  function drawScene() {
    webglUtils.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
    // Tell WebGL how to convert from clip space to pixels
    gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);
    // Clear the canvas AND the depth buffer.
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    // Turn on culling. By default backfacing triangles
    // will be culled.
    gl.enable(gl.CULL_FACE);
    // Enable the depth buffer
    gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);

    gl.enable( gl.BLEND );
    gl.blendEquation( gl.FUNC_ADD );
    gl.blendFunc( gl.ONE_MINUS_CONSTANT_ALPHA, gl.ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );

    // Tell it to use our program (pair of shaders)
    gl.useProgram(program);
    // Turn on the position attribute
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    // Bind the position buffer.
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
    // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 2;          // 3 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);

    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(centerLocation);
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, centerBuffer);
    // Tell the position attribute how to get data out of positionBuffer (ARRAY_BUFFER)
    var size = 3;          // 3 components per iteration
    var type = gl.FLOAT;   // the data is 32bit floats
    var normalize = false; // don't normalize the data
    var stride = 0;        // 0 = move forward size * sizeof(type) each iteration to get the next position
    var offset = 0;        // start at the beginning of the buffer
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(centerLocation, size, type, normalize, stride, offset);


    // Draw the geometry.
    var primitiveType = gl.TRIANGLES;
    var offset = 0;
    var count = points.length/2;
    gl.drawArrays(primitiveType,offset,count);

    // Call drawScene again next frame
    requestAnimationFrame(drawScene);
  }
}

loadScene();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
    background-color: wheat;
}

#html{
    background-color: wheat;
}
canvas {
  margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
  width: 90vw;
  height: 90vh;
  left: 5vw;
  top: 5vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/resources/webgl-utils.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Blending](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Blending) can only work if the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test) is not enabled:

<s>`gl.enable(gl.DEPTH_TEST);`</s>

When the depth test is enabled, the fragments may be discarded by the depth test, before they can be blended.